# LESS apply styles to element and its children

Tags: css, less

I have an element, `page-header` that I want to remove the margins from.  That element also has a child `h1` that I also want to remove the margin from.  Is there a shortcut syntax in LESS that allows me to do this.

Right now I have this:

```
.page-header,
.page-header h1{
    margin:0;
}
```

But I'm curious if there's something like:

```
.page-header &+ h1{
    margin:0;
}
```

that, when rendered, will give me CSS like my first code block above. *&+ doesn't work, I checked*

Comment: What exactly is the benefit of this solution over what's already in CSS?  I don't see how that's functionally different than just writing two comma separated rules, save for a couple characters.

Comment: @JoshBurgess That's all it is - saving a few characters.  It might be a bigger deal if the original declaration was longer, say `#body .content .top .page-header h1` for example.

Comment: Which should (probably) be nested to solve this problem, anyhow.  One of the beauties of using a pre-compiler.

Answer (score 2):

The ampersand can only be used with nesting:

```
.page-header {
    &, & h1{
        margin:0;
    }
}
```

For more information, see [my blog post](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-29/less-css-secrets-of-the-ampersand/).